# Test CharSequences for equality in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

The following test runs successfully:

```
assertEquals(a.toString(), b.toString());
```

The following does not:

```
assertEquals(a, b);
```

`a` is a `StringBuilder`, while `b` is a `CharSequence` of a different type.

Is there some way to test `CharSequence`s for equality without converting them to `String`s first?

Comment: Apart from comparing the length and then all characters one by one, no... Of course, if you use Java 8, you have an easier time

Comment: @fge I was hoping that JUnit already had an assert method that did exactly that, compare the length and then the characters.

Comment: @fredoverflow well, I use TestNG, so I can't really tell... assertj has methods for that however. But see my answer.

Comment: @fredoverflow You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can by using `CharBuffer`s:

```
assertEquals(CharBuffer.wrap(a), CharBuffer.wrap(b));
```

The javadoc of .equals for `CharBuffer` guarantees this:

```
Tells whether or not this buffer is equal to another object.

Two char buffers are equal if, and only if,

    They have the same element type,

    They have the same number of remaining elements, and

    The two sequences of remaining elements, considered independently of their starting positions, are pointwise equal.
```

Comment: @fredoverflow by the way, I confirm that assertj _does_ have assertions for CharSequence; so, if you're not against adding an extra lib... Assertj is really nice and I would personally recommend it but the decision is yours :)